# How to use github version control when you don't have any files?

Tags: github

I am working on a website and a game server, I want to use github version control but I don't really have any files to upload to github and when I do a release, it also releases the files.

How can I use the version control when I don't have any files to upload...? Or is there any better site for this?

Comment: What do you mean you don't have any files? What about source code, assets files, configuration files?

Comment: @Kuba well, I don't really want to make the code files public, I also use git for issue tracking and users can view that, I also wanted to use the releases but it releases the files that I upload to github, and I don't want to upload the website there...

Comment: Well that's what GitHub is for. You can create private organization repository (paid) where your source code won't be public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize an small GitHub repo (with just a README) and use [GitHub Release](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/) in order to:

- make a tag (even if the sources have not change)
- upload a binary associated to that tag: see "[Creating Releases](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/)"

But don't abuse that feature: if you upload files too big, too often, that repo might be invalidated by GitHub support.